# How can I add custom task to the Eclipse Gradle Task Tab?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

The Gradle tab in the Gradle Eclipse plugin has some predefined tasks as listed in the image:

[image]

**How can I add custom task to the Eclipse Gradle Task Tab?**

Comment: Have you tried making a custom gradle task as described at https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html (I'm relatively new to gradle, but I would imagine the plugin is just evaluating the tasks available).

Comment: yes I have custom tasks

Comment: Well, I've never used the eclipse plugin, so I can't say for sure - just as a sanity check, you can execute the custom tasks on command line, but they're not showing up in the plugin?  Is that an accurate description?

Comment: No, I need them in the list in eclipse

Answer (score 5):

Buildship Eclipse plugin only shows public tasks by default.

To show private tasks, select '*Show All Tasks*' from the view menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your project First, do you have a .gradle file?  This is the place to add your custom tasks.