# How can I add the Eclipse Gradle Task Tab?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I encountered the same issue as the following URL:
[How can I add custom task to the Eclipse Gradle Task Tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444128/how-can-i-add-custom-task-to-the-eclipse-gradle-task-tab)

I followed the movie to install the JavafxPorts and succeed until 10:05 ,But I don't know how to show the Eclipse Gradle Task Tab in my eclipse environment.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbQqnTnqaKk

Counld you let me know how to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

To show the ***Gradles Tasks* view**:

In the menu choose ***Window > Show View > Other...***, select ***Gradle > Gradle Tasks*** and click ***Open***.

Comment: But I also encountered the following error...                                                                        
:mergeClassesIntoJar FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeClassesIntoJar'.
> Cannot expand ZIP 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\multidex\library\libs\android-support-multidex.jar' as it does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Comment: Thank you for your kind help! I can make the .apk file.